# vlc cannot configure - needs libavcodec version 55

Tags: vlc

I am trying to build VLC through its source code and it gives me this error everytime I run ./configure

> configure: error: Requested 'libavcodec >= 55.0.0' but version of
>   libavcodec is 54.35.0. Pass --disable-avcodec to ignore this error.

I have executed the command `apt-get build-dep vlc` and still I get this error. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What Linux distribution and version is this?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 TLS 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the contrib system to build your own copy of libavcodec  instead of using the one in your system. See the [The "Contrib" method] in https://wiki.videolan.org/UnixCompile/